# ListFragment doesn't seem be inflating

Tags: java, android

Hoping someone can help. I'm having an issue it seems inflating my view. My goal is to display a list of items in a custom layout using a custom array adapter. I re-worked some of my original code using another SO post, but where my simple adapter worked fine, the new list doesn't display. Please see below:

This is my Fragment class.

```
HomeFeedFragment.java

    public class HomeFeedFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<MainEvent> items;
    private MainEventListViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homefeed,
                container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //GetEvents is just a test method to return a list of pre-filled event objects
        items = GlobalList.GetEvents();
        adapter = new MainEventListViewAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.list, items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


      @Override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // do something with the data
      }

}
```

My custom row layout xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Heading Text -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventheader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Event Description -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventdescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_below="@id/eventheader"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

    <!-- Posted Time -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventpostedtime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/eventheader"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="SmallSp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The actual fragment layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    

    <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView> 


</LinearLayout>
```

And my custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MainEventListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MainEvent> {
    private Context context;
    private List<MainEvent> eventList;

    public MainEventListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<MainEvent> eventList){
        super(context, textViewResourceId, eventList);
        this.context = context;
        //this.eventList = eventList;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtEventHeader;
        TextView txtEventDescription;
        TextView txtEventPostedTime;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        if(eventList!=null){
            return eventList.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public MainEvent getItem(int position){
        if(eventList!=null){
            return eventList.get(position);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
        if(eventList!=null){
            return eventList.get(position).hashCode();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        MainEvent rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homefeed_rowlayout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtEventHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventheader);
            holder.txtEventDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventdescription);
            holder.txtEventPostedTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventpostedtime);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtEventHeader.setText(rowItem.getHeadline());
        holder.txtEventDescription.setText(rowItem.getDescription());
        holder.txtEventPostedTime.setText(rowItem.getPostedTime());

        /*TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
        text.setText(m.getHeadline());
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        imageView.setTag(m.getImageURL());
        //DownloadImageTask dt = new DownloadImageTask();
        dt.execute(imageView);

        return v;*/
        return convertView;
    }

    public List<MainEvent> getEventList(){
        return eventList;
    }

    public void setEventList(List<MainEvent> eventList){
        this.eventList = eventList;
    }

}
```

^ I initially had an Async Task in this class to retrieve images for each item, but I've removed all of that for now.

I don't get any actual errors in LogCat, no crashes or anything, the View just isn't inflating. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to debug and check if `getView` is getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing. I found out the issue. Apparently, I forgot to uncomment the line in the adapter constructor that initializes the event list:

```
//this.eventList = eventList;
```

I'd commented it out temporarily to fix another bug. Working fine now, but thanks for your suggestion.